# Want to fadeout the present web page and fade in the next one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fadeout the present web page slowly and fade In the next page when I click on the link for any other page (in my web site).

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css("display","none");
    $('body').fadeIn(2000);

    $("a:transition").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation=this.href();
        $('body').fadeOut('slow', 0, redirectPage);
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location=linkLocation;
    };
    });

http://jsfiddle.net/Rohanhola/vmpnc9f0/2/
```

With the above code, I'm able to fade In the contents of the next page, the fadeout on the present page doesn't seem to work!!

open for suggestions!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change this.href to $(this).attr('href');

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to disable default link behavior. So, your link's anchor needs to be set to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

Then, instead of href, you can set custom data attribute for the link target.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="/setTheLocationYouWant></a>
```

And lastly, you'll only modify your JS a bit.

```
$("a:transition").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation=this.data('target'); //modified bit
        $('body').fadeOut('slow', 0, redirectPage);
    });
```

EDIT: Simple version (Only JS changes)

```
$("a:transition").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation=this.href();
    $('body').fadeOut('slow', 0, redirectPage);
});
```

You're using `.click()` which automatically invokes the default link behavior. Instead of it, use `.on()` method. Also, you forgot to forward the `event` itself as an argument.

Comment: nope. the page still exits abruptly. No fadeout! :(

Comment: Try erasing the zero from the fadeOut method. Use `$('body').fadeOut('slow', redirectPage);`

Comment: same result! :)

next page fadein = OK
present page fadeout=Not ok